# Using Greater Than operator in SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum a table's column in Excel 2010 based on a few criteria and can't seem to get the >= operator to work.

The column I'm trying to use as a criteria is Order.Probability, which has values from 25% to 100%. When I type "=100%" I get the sum, but ">=90%" returns 0.

```
=SUMIFS(Revenue[Revenue.NetNetRevenue], Revenue[Order.Probability], ">=90%", Revenue[Revenue.MonthYear], "=January 2017")
```

Comment: could you post a sample of the spreadsheet?

Comment: @Benjamin, please add some sample data and expected results in your question, If you do that, surely we can help you.

Comment: Try if the following works: =SUMIFS(Revenue[Revenue.NetNetRevenue], Revenue[Order.Probability], ">=.9", Revenue[Revenue.MonthYear], "January 2017")

Comment: Described behavior is exactly what happens if `Revenue[Order.Probability]` contains the "25%"..."100%" as text instead of 25%...100% as number values. Condition "=100%" will work then since it compares the text "100%" with the text "100%". But condition ">=90%" cannot work since ">=" leads to numeric comparison and the text "100%" is not >=0.9.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your table references are incorrect.
And I don't think it is % versus using decimals.
In the table below In E3, I have the formula

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[Amount], Table1[Id], "=4", Table1[Probability], ">=21%")
```

and it works whether I use 21% or .21. 
So I suspect your references of how you use the columns, you should be able to use Table.column] and I am not sure if table references are not correct

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you should enter either `>=90%` without quotes or `">="&90%`.

In the second case you can substitute a cell reference for the 90%.